# Copy text to clipboard using Zero Clipboard in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, copy, zeroclipboard

I am trying to use **Zero** **Clipboard** to copy text from **Textbox** to **Clipboard** when client clicks a **Button**. I am trying this for many days but no luck to make this work.

In Scenario, i have one **Textbox** which render data from the **Database**. I have one **Button** which when client clicks should copy text of the **Textbox**. I have tried following but its not working.

Some help will be appreciated.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('/Scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf');
    </script>



<script>
    function test() {

        ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('/Scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf');
        //create client
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();

        //event
        clip.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
            clip.setText(document.getElementById('TextBox2').value);

        });
        clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
            alert('copied: ' + text);

        });
        //glue it to the button
        clip.glue('d_clip_button');

    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" BorderStyle="None"  Enabled="False" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Width="213px"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="d_clip_button" runat="server" Text="Copy" OnClientClick="javascript:test();" />
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="copy-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" title="Click to copy me.">
Copy to Clipboard</button>
<script src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//In Main.js file
// main.js
var clip = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button"), {
moviePath: "/path/to/ZeroClipboard.swf"
} );

clip.on( 'load', function(client) {
// alert( "movie is loaded" );
} );

clip.on( 'complete', function(client, args) {
this.style.display = 'none'; // "this" is the element that was clicked
alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + args.text );
} );

clip.on( 'mouseover', function(client) {
// alert("mouse over");
} );

clip.on( 'mouseout', function(client) {
// alert("mouse out");
} );

clip.on( 'mousedown', function(client) {

// alert("mouse down");
} );

clip.on( 'mouseup', function(client) {
// alert("mouse up");
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

        <div id="d_clip_button" style="border:1px solid black; padding:20px;">Copy To Clipboard</div>

        <script language="JavaScript">
            var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
            var myTextToCopy = "Hi, this is the text to copy!";
            clip.setText( myTextToCopy );
            clip.glue( 'd_clip_button' );
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're trying to pick element by wrong id. Since you use webforms, correct way is:

```
getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>')
```

Also, following unobtrusive js style good solution might look like:

```
$().ready(function () {
    ZeroClipboard.setDefaults({ moviePath: "/Scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf" });

    var clip = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById('YourButtonId')); //or '<%=YourButton.ClientID%>' if you use asp.net button

    clip.on('complete', function (client, args) {
        alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + args.text);
    });
});
```

Also your button should have data attribute `data-clipboard-target`(actually there're three ways to do it). Setting data-attributes to webforms control is tricky, so you might want to avoid using asp.net button here and do it like:

```
<input type="button" value="clickme" id="YourButtonId" data-clipboard-target="<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>"/>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I am still not able to make this work..Can you please implement this in jsfiddle.